ERROR: ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970) handshake failed
Hey I have Ionic project where I'm showing an webpage in app
Now It's working perfectly fine in my smartphone(Android 13) but in another device(Android 8) I got this error in my console Error: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
I'm stuck with this error for more than 3 days If Anyone knows solution please help me out
Note: It's working perfectly fine if I try to open that url in browser
webview.html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe src="https://stgdowndev.mantratecapp.com/Download/Admin/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</ion-content>

menifest.xml
 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
          android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
          tools:targetApi="n">

network_security_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">stgdowndev.mantratecapp.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>


This can happen if the server uses a certificate issued by an intermediate CA that belongs to a root CA the older Android version has not installed. You ca try to add the used root CA certificate manually to your app as shown here: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#ConfigCustom
